# Event KeyCode Jquery no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Buen dia, Tengo un problema al intentar programar el KeyCode event. Estoy seguro que no tiene que ver con la biblioteca de JQuery porque ya probe una alerta, lo cual me indica que esta funcionando bien.

Espero puedan ayudarme, he revisado varias veces el código pero no logo percatarme del error.

Dejo el fragmento del código donde se encuentra el input y la parte de js donde se encuentra el evento.

Gracias de antemano

```
           <tbody>
                        <tr>
                                <td data-th="Product">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <form id="bestellung" class="kauft" action="" method="post">

                                            <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"><img src="<?php echo $daten[$i]['foto'];?>" alt="..." class="img-responsive"/></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <h4 class="nomargin"><?php echo $daten[$i]['name']; ?></h4>
                                                <p><h4><b><em>Details:</em></b></h4></p>
                                                <p><b>Produkt Typ:</b> <?php echo $daten[$i]['ptyp']; ?></p>
                                                <p><b>Herkunfsland:</b> #########</p>
                                                <p>T<b>ransportwege:</b>#########</p>
                                                <p><b>Containertyp:</b>#######</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-th="Price"><?php echo "€" . number_format( $daten[$i]['preis'],2); ?></td>
                                    <td data-th="Price"><?php echo "€" . number_format( $daten[$i]['preis'],2); ?></td>
                                    <td data-th="Price"><?php echo "€" . number_format( $daten[$i]['preis'],2); ?></td>
                                    <td data-th="Quantity">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="<?php echo $daten[$i]['menge'];?>"
                                        data-preis="<?php echo "€" . number_format( $daten[$i]['preis'],2); ?>"
                                        data-id="<?php echo $daten[$i]['produkt_id']; ?>"
                                        class="menge">
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center"><?php echo $daten[$i]['menge']* $daten[$i]['preis'];?></strong></td>

                                    <td class="actions" data-th="">
                                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>

<tfoot>
                            <tr class="visible-xs">
                                <td class="subtotal"><strong><?php echo $daten[$i]['menge']* $daten[$i]['preis'];?></strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="2" class="hidden-xs"></td>
                                <td class="hidden-xs text-center">
<strong>Total <?php echo ($daten[$i]['menge']*$daten[$i]['preis'])+$summe;?>
</strong></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </form>
    </div>

<?php $summe=($daten[$i]['menge']*$daten[$i]['preis'])+$summe;
}
}else {
echo "<center><h2>El carro de compras esta vacio</h2></center>";
}

echo '<center><h2 id="summe"> Summe: '.$summe.'</h2></center>';
if($summe!=0){


}
```

Codigo Jquery

```
var inicio=function () {
$(".menge").keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val()!=''){
        if(e.keyCode==32){
            var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
            var preis=$(this).attr('data-preis');
            var menge=$(this).val();
            $(this).parentsUntil('.Produkt').find('.subtotal').text('Subtotal: '+(preis*menge));
            $.post('./js/modificarDatos.php',{
                Id:id,
                Preis:preis,
                Menge:menge
            },function(e){
                $("#summe").text('summe: '+e);
              });
           }
        }
    });
}
$(document).on('ready',inicio);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que tienes duplicado el atributo `class` en tu `input`, entonces el segundo atributo `class` es ignorado. Puedes verificarlo listando los elemento con clase `.menge` con `$('.menge')` te darás cuenta que no está retornando nada.

Tu input debe quedar así:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center menge" value="<?php echo $daten[$i]['menge'];?>"
                                        data-preis="<?php echo "€" . number_format( $daten[$i]['preis'],2); ?>"
                                        data-id="<?php echo $daten[$i]['produkt_id']; ?>">
```

---

Por otro lado, tienes una etiqueta mal cerrada, el `form` que inicia dentro del `tbody`, pero termina fuera del `table` y también tienes un`h4` dentro de un `p`, lo cual es incorrecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Ali, corregí los errores que me comentas te e incluso elimine un atributo class pero sigue sin funcionar. Ves alguna otra posibilidad en donde pueda encontrarse el error?

Comment: Qué raro, yo lo he probado y funcionó, no publiqué el código por que estaba largo y no se iba a entender, no debes eliminar el class, debes mover `menge ` al primer class(acabo de editar mi respuesta), luego fíjate si en la consola te bota algún error, también prueba $('.menge') en la consola para que veas si jQuery está que te devuelve el input.

Comment: Nuevamente gracias Ali, hice los cambios exactamente como lo mencionas arriba y con una alerta comprobé que funciona. Al solucionar ese error me aparece otro cuando quiero imprimir el subtotal "NaN". He estado investigando pero aun no encuentro la solución, se refiere al valor de las variables ?

Comment: Marca la pregunta como solucionada y crea otra pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Tenia un problema similar con esto lo solucione